# How to vertically center image, text in materializecss btn

Tags: css, materialize

creating a button using `btn` class, 
and add image, text with in that

here both are vertically center if the image size is small,  ( like 40% )

but if the image size is 90% of the `btn` 
text is not vertically center

can any one help me, to create a button, with a text and an image
and text will be vertically center.

please check the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fWyyjDTO4XfpyEHmrfji?p=preview)

html:

```
<a href="#" class="btn">   
  <img class="" src="svg.svg" alt="">
  <span>Testing</span>
</a>
```

css :

```
img {
  height: 90%;
}
```

Comment: want the image, text vertically center -   even the image size changes ( 1% - 100% )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plunker add below css line:

```
img{width:20px;height:20px;vertical-align:middle}
span{padding-left:7px;}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, adding `vertical-align:middle` on `img` works, ( i tried of adding that for element which contains text )

Answer (score 1):

try this i've added the `svg` inside an `i tag` and controlled the `height` of the `svg` inside it, see the code snippet

```css
i{
width:auto; text-align:center;
}
i svg {
width:auto;height:40%;display:block;float:left;margin-right:10px;position:relative;top:33%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

 <a href="#" class="btn"> 
<!-- added the svg to the html -->  
<i><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="384" height="448" viewBox="0 0 384 448">
<path fill="#000" d="M246.25 243.5c4.25 0 45 21.25 46.75 24.25 0.5 1.25 0.5 2.75 0.5 3.75 0 6.25-2 13.25-4.25 19-5.75 14-29 23-43.25 23-12 0-36.75-10.5-47.5-15.5-35.75-16.25-58-44-79.5-75.75-9.5-14-18-31.25-17.75-48.5v-2c0.5-16.5 6.5-28.25 18.5-39.5 3.75-3.5 7.75-5.5 13-5.5 3 0 6 0.75 9.25 0.75 6.75 0 8 2 10.5 8.5 1.75 4.25 14.5 38.25 14.5 40.75 0 9.5-17.25 20.25-17.25 26 0 1.25 0.5 2.5 1.25 3.75 5.5 11.75 16 25.25 25.5 34.25 11.5 11 23.75 18.25 37.75 25.25 1.75 1 3.5 1.75 5.5 1.75 7.5 0 20-24.25 26.5-24.25zM195.5 376c86.5 0 157-70.5 157-157s-70.5-157-157-157-157 70.5-157 157c0 33 10.5 65.25 30 92l-19.75 58.25 60.5-19.25c25.5 16.75 55.75 26 86.25 26zM195.5 30.5c104 0 188.5 84.5 188.5 188.5s-84.5 188.5-188.5 188.5c-31.75 0-63.25-8-91.25-23.5l-104.25 33.5 34-101.25c-17.75-29.25-27-63-27-97.25 0-104 84.5-188.5 188.5-188.5z"></path>
</svg>
</i>
  <span>Testing</span>
</a>
```

Comment: thank you friend, but here image is not center - if we want to reduce the size of image to fit our needs

Comment: i thinks, now it is good, if so mark it as resolved, and give it an upvote, thanks.

Comment: if changed the height the image is not center ..  `i svg {
width:auto;height:40%;display:block;float:left;
}`

Comment: i've added `position relative; top:33%;` is this what you'r looking for !

Answer (score -1):

Put to the image css a new atributte vertical-align:middle;